# Unable to draw method in Chart.js, v2 can't be found

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I had previously installed my chart.js current version with bower. 
For different reasons I have to use chart.js: https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/releases/tag/2.0.0-alpha3

I changed the name on my bower file to the current version and bower installed. But I keep getting this error.

> TypeError: (intermediate value).Line is not a function

Here is my code:

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(dat);
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In Chart.js 2.0.0 Alpha 3 you will need to create your chart like so:

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx , {
    type: "line",
    data: dat, 
});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/m73ktoux/)

At least right now it doesn't have `new Chart().Line()` like the older version.

What your error basically means is that it was expecting a semi-colon after `Chart(ctx)`.

Comment: Thanks dude. I posted a different question b/c now my html won't get rendered. Hope you can help @Spencer

Comment: Thanks! I'd also been stumped by this. couple extra Q's if you don't mind; how do you pass in options (I'm now on 2.0.0-alpha4) and in your fiddle example the lines are animated as they appear, where is that set? coping your code exactly works, but doesn't have the animation.

Comment: @Sujimichi You can set the animation as an option `animationEasing`, although this option is already set by default in both alpha-3 and alpha-4. I'm not really sure why it's not working in this case, to me it seems like it could be a bug.

Comment: Hi,  i am using version 2.3.0 but its not show tooltips.